# Trying to create a good rollup react project

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, rollup

I try to create a web app with rollup, typescript and react (tsx).

I have a source folder, with all files I want to compile.
I need all ts and tsx files are compiled in javascript, and are usable directly by a web browser.

This is my current architecture :

[image: Rollup react project]

The aim is to put this webapp in an ASP.net project, and call js files, compiled inside the dist folder, by the browser.

I try a lot of things since few months, but that didn't work ..

Someone have an idea for the configuration of rollup, tsconfig and package.json ?

Thank you in advance for any help !

Edit : I add the project on github so you can see where I am :
https://github.com/marquito73/create-react-rollup-webapp